# Matrix exponentiation by Lagrange interpolation formula

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Okay so I'm trying to get my head around calculating powers and functions of matrices.
So given a matrix $A=PJP^{-1}$ suppose we wish to calculate $A^n$ using the Lagrange interpolation formula as opposed to the telescoping and tedious product $A^n=PJ^nP^{-1}$.
We then wish to solve the following simultaneous equations for the interpolation function $h(A)$
$f^{(t)}(\alpha_j)=h^{(t)}(\alpha_j), 1 \leq j \leq k, 0 \leq t<m_j$ for eigenvalues $\alpha_j$

In every example I've encountered including using this to calculate $e^A$ the above simultaneous equations has only had 2 equations. Is this always the case or is the number of equations dependent on the minimal equation for the matrix?

Probably a silly question but I felt I needed to clarify whether or not there was a correspondence from the degree of the minimal equation to the number of equations to solve to find the interpolation function.

Comment: $f(A)$ is defined to equal $A^n$ just in case it wasn't clear

Comment: also ie the interpolation formula in every case I've seen $h(A)$ has reduced to $h(A)=\alpha A+\beta I_n$